# unresolved dependencies (held back packages) seemingly unfixable

Tags: debian, apt, dependencies, aptitude, synaptic

I was having some problems with LibreOffice Draw, and since I couldn't find a solution for it I decided to uninstall and do a clean install. If I recall correctly This is what I've used:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge libreoffice*

sudo apt-get clean

sudo apt-get autoremove
```

Restarted my PC and all. The problem is that when I want to install it again via aptitude (apt-get doesnt' work either) using:

```
aptitude install libreoffice
```

I get a message saying (text is too long to paste here)

https://pastebin.com/BXTuAqrP

Now i've tried autoremove -s, apt update, upgrade, apt-get install -f, --fix-broken and according to these comands i don't have any broken or held back packages. I've also use Synaptic manager and the Broken package list is empty. I tried install Libreoffice from there but I get the same error. Only a bit more clear.

https://pastebin.com/iRMkywR1

I've enabled all downloads in software & updates and everything.

When I type on terminal

```
apt search libreoffice
```

I get this (there are alot of remnants)

https://pastebin.com/Qa5LnuS5

I don't know what to do, or how to delete it! It's driving me insane. I spent hours and hours looking for solutions on the internet, I've tried everything but to no avail!

Im running Debian9

Please do help me out.

Comment: Welcome to U&L ,You have a mixed sources (Ubuntu 18 + Debian) . Please add the content of your `sources.list`: `cat /etc/apt/sources.list` and `cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*`.

Answer (score 0):

<s>Are you pulling software from non-stretch repositories? I've searched on https://packages.debian.org and can't find a `libreoffice-core` package that requires `libboost-locale1.65.1` as your log indicates. If you are, please try disabling them temporarily and installing `libreoffice` again.</s>

What is the output of `apt-cache policy libreoffice-core`? Running this might give you more information on where `libreoffice` is coming from.

Additionally, `apt-get` takes regex and not globbing, so removing all libreoffice packages would actually be `apt-get purge '.*libreoffice.*'`.

Edit: From your third pastebin link it appears you're pulling software from Ubuntu repositories. **This is definitely not supported** as Ubuntu and Debian software **do not mix** and most likely the source of your installation woes. I recommend that you purge all Ubuntu components from your system, remove all Ubuntu repositories from `apt`, run `apt-get update; apt-get -f install`, and try installing `libreoffice` again.